# how to average every nth columns of a data frame? i.e. column 1&10&19&..., 2&11&20&..., 3&12&21&

Tags: r, dataframe

I managed to sort my excel files into a single data frame however, due to my limited knowledge I made it so that the data presents itself in a continuous way (see below):

time Event1 Event2 Event3 ... EventID8 time Event1 Event2 Event3 ...EventID8

SO I need to find a way to average every nth column in a away that if I decide to import more excel files the script would still work as intended?

I have tried looking for functions that would do this but can't find something that would match exactly what I need. This is my first ever use of R and if you can walk me through the details of each command it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the columns to be averaged are having the pattern of 'Event' followed by digits, and want to average only the columns that have same duplicate prefix, then a method would be to use `split.default` on the `Event` subset of columns by removing the suffix part (if it is a data.frame as data.frame will create suffix .1, .2, etc for duplicate column names so as to make it unique), loop over the `list` with `sapply` and get the `rowMeans`

```
nm1 <- grep("^Event\\d+$", names(df1), value = TRUE)
sapply(split.default(df1[nm1], sub("\\..*", "", nm1)), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Another option would be subset by position index (not clear about the total number of columns - may need changes in `1:3` to `1:(ncol(df1)-18` or so

```
sapply(1:3, \(i)  rowSums(df1[i + (0:2)*9], na.rm = TRUE))
```